# Node.js: Cannot find module but the specified path exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, node-modules

I am currently developing my own npm package and I created a separate project to download this package from npm for an independent test. The package is being developed in typescript and I have a main file with several additional module files. In my main file, I am importing all of the classes from the other modules, then exporting all of them under the main file. I don't know if this is good practice but when I run the main file on the test project, it says it can't find the module when the path it specifies exists in the working directory.

**Code Snippets:**

Main file:

```js
import { EventBus } from "./modules/eventbus/eventbus";
import { EventHandler } from "./modules/eventbus/eventhandler";
import { EventType } from "./modules/eventbus/eventtype";
import { Event } from "./modules/eventbus/event";
import { SemVer } from "./modules/semver";
export { SemVer, Event, EventBus, EventHandler, EventType };
```

Error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/workspaces/epic-engine-testing/node_modules/epic-engine/lib/modules/eventbus/eventbus' imported from /workspaces/epic-engine-testing/node_modules/epic-engine/lib/index.js
```

Working directory:

[image]

Testing file:

```js
import { EventBus, EventHandler, EventType, Event } from "epic-engine";

class SomeType extends EventType {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

const eventbus = new EventBus();
const handler = new EventHandler<SomeType>(eventbus, "type", () => {});
eventbus.createHandler(handler);
const event = new Event<SomeType>(eventbus, new SomeType(), "type");
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/esm": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.3",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  },
  "name": "epic-engine",
  "description": "Pure TS engine developed by EpicPuppy613",
  "version": "0.1.0-dev.5",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --config jestconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "prepare": "npm run build",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm test && npm run lint",
    "preversion": "npm run lint",
    "version": "git add -A src",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/EpicPuppy613/epic-engine.git"
  },
  "author": "EpicPuppy613",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/EpicPuppy613/epic-engine/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/EpicPuppy613/epic-engine#readme",
  "files": [
    "lib/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I tried a bunch of things including changing the references to use `.js`, using absolute paths instead, and changing some settings in `tsconfig.json`.

**Why is Node.js not finding the submodules or would it be better to export the modules in a different way?**

Comment: Could you share the package.json of your library too?

Comment: @KavianRabbani I edited the original question with the package.json

Comment: Thanks! Does removing `files` property from it help?

Comment: the `files` property is important for publishing the package

Comment: What does your `tsconfig` look like?

Answer (score 1):

After compiling the *ts* files into *js* files, wherever you have *import* syntax, Node.js looks for `.js` files to resolve them. So it needs to be explicitly given a module name with `.js` extension in *import*.

You may need to read [this doc](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_specifiers) on how the *import* mechanism works in Node.js.

To fix this issue, you have multiple choices(**since the target you've defined is ES6**):

1. change `moduleResolution` to `nodeNext` and add `.js` extension whenever you would importing modules in typescript:

```js
import { EventBus } from "./modules/eventbus/eventbus.js";
import { EventHandler } from "./modules/eventbus/eventhandler.js";
import { EventType } from "./modules/eventbus/eventtype.js";
...
```

You don't need to be worried about it, typescript is well smart. Based on [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577#issuecomment-754941937) from one of typescript contributor:

> .js file extensions are now allowed

---

2. Using [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) package. The rollup package won't manipulate your files. Instead, it bundles your output files.

Comment: I'm confused because when I test it locally, it works fine, but when I'm importing it into another project, it doesn't work

Comment: It's also weird because I tried adding `.js` to the imports but then typescript raised a compile-time error for it

Comment: Update: adding `.js` to the imports does not work, just tested it, it still returns the same error.

Comment: What errors typescript shows you? and would you please double-check and go through the compiled folder to see if the javascript imports have `.js` extension?

Comment: It still gives me a `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/workspaces/epic-engine-testing/node_modules/epic-engine/lib/modules/eventbus/eventbus.js' imported from /workspaces/epic-engine-testing/node_modules/epic-engine/lib/index.js` error

Comment: No idea, if you compiled it successfully, and published it over NPM. It shouldn't be any issues. Since you defined `ES6` as the target, I'm not sure if there is another way rather than what I mentioned.

Comment: Just coming to this in May '23... Why does using a .js file extension in import of file work when file is actually a .ts extension? Makes no sense to me, but does seem to have worked..

Answer (score 0):

### Save time with `npm link` command

> I created a separate project **to download this package from npm** for an independent test.

First, you can use the handy `npm link` command to save yourself the trouble of uploading your package just so you can test. As per [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link) the `npm link` command:

> ...is handy for installing your own stuff, so that you can work on it and test iteratively without having to continually rebuild.

### Install your package as a dependency

With that out of the way, I think the hint is in the error message. Note it says:

> `Cannot find module /workspaces/epic-engine-testing/node_modules/...`

Here it seems Node is looking for the file in the `epic-engine-testing` project, so you must have the `package.json` file for the *test* project reference your package (i.e. the one you want to test). So go into your `epic-engine-testing` project folder and at the terminal type `npm install epic-engine@0.1.0-dev.5`. That should install your package so it can be found. If that doesn't resolve it, you'll need to share the `package.json` file for the `epic-engine-testing` to help us see what's going on.

### Using the `export { ... } from '...'` syntax

Your main file can use the [re-exports synax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#re-exports) and be simplified to this when exporting:

```
export { EventBus } from "./modules/eventbus/eventbus";
export { EventHandler } from "./modules/eventbus/eventhandler";
export { EventType } from "./modules/eventbus/eventtype";
export { Event } from "./modules/eventbus/event";
export { SemVer } from "./modules/semver";

// the line below is not necessary when using above syntax.
// export { SemVer, Event, EventBus, EventHandler, EventType };
```